# slow csr matrix construction

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm creating a csr matrix using the `csr_matrix((data, indices, indptr), shape=[row, col])` method. It took me more than 4x more time to execute the construction method `csr_matrix()` than building up `data, indices, indptr` themselves. Since I already have the `(data, indices, indptr)` tuple, shouldn't it be trival (and fast) to construct a csr matrix?

my code and time statistics is like this:

```
data = ...  # 2.207s
indices = ...  # 11.065s       
indptr = ...  # 0.047s          
matrix = csr_matrix((data, indices, indptr), shape=(row, col))  # 57.806s
```

Comment: Look at the data buffer pointer, `.__array_interface__['data']`, for the input arrays, and the corresponding `matrix` attributes.  If they don't match, then it's doing some sort of copying and/or transformation.  Check other attributes like `dtype` and `shape`.

Comment: `sparse.compressed._cs_matrix` is the class that creates a `csr` matrix.  Check it's code to see if your arguments match the `no-copy` condition (look also at `np.array`).

Comment: Isn't it faster to create a coo_matrix and then convert it to csr?

Comment: @Forzaa No I don't think so. It would have to convert the data in coo_matrix into `(data, indices, indptr)` tuple anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems like the arrays you're passing are large, so it's possible that they're getting copied somewhere and the resulting memory issues are causing the slowdown.

There are a few ways that your arrays could be getting copied. If any of these conditions are false, you'll be incurring copies:

- `indices` and `indptr` need to be of an appropriate index dtype.
- All three need to be numpy arrays (`numpy.ndarray`)
- The `copy` kwarg needs to be `False`. It's false by default, so this is unlikely to be the issue.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to build `data` `indices` and `indptr` as `numpy.array`. The time for constructing `csr_matrix` is negligible now. Really help tip.